# Displaying row and column of selected pixel in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, I can use the identify tool to get the pixel value and the coordinate for a selected pixel, I also have a coordinate capture tool to display the selected pixel in another coordinate system.

But how can I display the row/column of this particular pixel, which x and y of the total dimension this pixel is located at?